# Vim YouCompleteMe unavailable

Tags: linux, vim, youcompleteme

I installed YCM but it says:

```
YouCompleteMe unavailable: requires Vim compiled with Python (2.6+ or 3.3+) support.
```

So I went to Google for help, and the result is that I have to

```
./configure --enable-pythoninterp=yes
```

But where is the `./configure` script? I don't have it in my usr/share/vim/vim80
Please help

Comment: This Q **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related sites http://superuser.com OR http://vi.stackexchange.com . Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck

Comment: Off-topic. BTW Debian (so probably Ubuntu) has a `vim-youcompleteme` package

Comment: Did you download a binary of vim, or build it from source yourself?

Answer (score 3):

YouCompleteMe requires manual installation.

Take a look at the [instructions](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe#installation)

Comment: Especially [this](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Building-Vim-from-source) if you need to build from source (with `./configure`).

Answer (score 1):

By the evidence, you showed on the question post, I guess you used [`vim-plug`](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug), For having **YouCompleteMe** on `vim-plug` you should open the `.vimrc` file and then add below command inside it:

```
Plug 'ycm-core/YouCompleteMe', { 'do': './install.py --tern-completer' }
```

The second part `{ 'do': './install.py --tern-completer' }` means after installing, some part of **YouCompleteMe** should be built with `./install.py --tern-completer` command. If you just add the `Plug 'https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe'` command in the `.vimrc` the file then you should make it manually:

```
cd ~/.vim/plugged/YouCompleteMe && ./install.py --tern-completer
```

Comment: This answered OP's question. Fixed my problem with following error message: "YouCompleteMe unavailable: requires Vim compiled with Python (3.6.0+) support"

Comment: UPDATE: This didn't completely solve the underlying issue OP had. I also had to add the following command in terminal (Linux user): python3 -m pip install --user --upgrade pynvim

Answer (score 0):

The configure script is in the vim folder you clone from git. As the Ingo Karkat says you can follow the instructions provided there, just remember that you should omit the `--with-python-config-dir=` parameter because it's deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to missing compiled youcompleteme

For mac- Install cmake

```
   brew install cmake
   cd ~/.vim/bundle/youcompleteme && ./install.sh
```

This got mine fixed. This assumed you have clone/ or using vundle for vim plugins